# iOS, how to localize an app into Chinese, with numbering?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, localization

My app shows numbers of buttons, the number symbols.

Can iOS produce the localization of number symbols based on language selection, if so how?

I'm outputting string, I guess I will need some kind of regional formatting functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, make your project to support Chinese:

[image]

**Second**, add a Localizable.strings file with the translated text like:
[image]

**Third**, make the file localized for Chinese:

[image]
[image]

**Finally**, you are able to use the translation like:

```
self.helloLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Hello!", @"A text for saying hello label");
```

The "你好!" will be displayed if your iPhone's language is Chinese.

For number converting:

```
NSString *localizedString = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber: @(1314) 
        numberStyle: NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle]; 

NSLog(@"Formatted string:%@",localizedString); 
//Formatted string:一千三百一十四  (if system region is China)
```

If you want directly convert the number symbols:

```
- (NSString *)getNumberSymbols:(NSInteger)number {
    NSArray *symbols = @[@"零",@"一",@"二",@"三",@"四",@"五",@"六",@"七",@"八",@"九"];
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)number];

    for (int i = 0;i<symbols.count;i++) {

        [result replaceOccurrencesOfString:
         [NSMutableString stringWithFormat: @"%ld",(long)i] 
                               withString: symbols[i] 
                                  options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch 
                                    range: NSMakeRange(0, result.length)];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or:

```
- (NSString *)getNumberSymbols:(NSInteger)number {
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)number];
    for (int i = 0;i<=9;i++) {

        NSString *localizedNumber = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:@(i) 
          numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];

        [result replaceOccurrencesOfString:
               [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)i] 
                   withString: localizedNumber 
                      options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch 
                        range: NSMakeRange(0, result.length)];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Use it:

```
NSString *result = [self getNumberSymbols:134]; //Output: 一三四
```

Comment: Thanks, Yeah already done German, however I'm wondering if iOS has methods to convert numbers perhaps with regional setting methods ? Also, you appear to be Chinese, what system fonts are best for traditional, simplified, I also need to find out about Japanese best font. Thanks

Comment: @Jules, I updated the answer for number converting. And we usually use default system font for Chinese.

Comment: The result is: Formatted string:1314 with `NSNumberFormatterNoStyle`

Comment: So there's isn't a style which will produce chinese numbers? Also, can I also ask which application regions (from the scheme) is simplified chinese used in there's china, Hong Kong, Macau, there's also Taiwan.

Comment: `NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle` cannot satisfy you needs? I think system will also make proper numbers with this style for Hong Kong, Macau etc.

Comment: It's OK if you only have single numbers, like 1 -> 一, 4 -> 四, 9 -> 九. Single Chinese number's width is likely equal to two English characters width.  If you have more than one number, that will be a problem, like 24 ->  二十四.

Comment: Is there a ios function which will give me these numbers ?

Comment: It's already given with my answer, you will get 三(3) : `NSString *localizedString = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:@(3) numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];`

Comment: Looking at the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumberformatterstyle?language=objc `NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle
Specifies a spell-out format; for example, 1234.5678 is represented as “one thousand two hundred thirty-four point five six seven eight”.`  this says it will produce words not symbols ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingLocaleData/InternationalizingLocaleData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH13-SW1  And search "Using Preset Number Styles". Why don't you try the code with Xcode and Simulator with region China?

Comment: You will get word '三' instead of 3, if your device's region is China.

Comment: I could have numbers as high as 144, that will too wide, just tried one hundred forty four on google translate :(

Comment: So it's now an  auto layout issue, not the localization. Please consider to make more dynamic constraints for buttons, or find way to adjust them dynamically to fit wider width.

Comment: No I just want the number symbols not words

Comment: I add a function in answer to directly convert numbers.

Comment: Ah ok, shame it not included in iOS

Comment: Is it the same for chinese traditional ?

Comment: Traditional: 零壹貳參肆伍陸柒捌玖

Comment: Hey, I notice when using google translate it provides a none Chinese symbols version of words as well, should I use these for keywords? Thanks.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: multiplication - 乘法 -Chéngfǎ - Chinese symbols don't seem to work in itunes.

Comment: Just * for multiplication, / for division. Chinese people know the symbols.

Comment: Sorry I'm being a bit off topic, I'm talking about app store keywords